# приведение дробной части числа в целую

Tags: c++, алгоритм, циклы, числа

получаете на ввод действительное число ( `12.345`) нужно его дробную часть `0.345`перевести в целое число `345` и вывести на экран. В чем ошибка в цикле?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    double r;

    cin>>r;

    double p=1;

    double i_r,i_r2;
    double ost_r=modf(r,&i_r);
    cout<<modf(ost_r,&i_r2);
    while(modf(ost_r,&i_r2)!=0)
    {
        ost_r*=10;
        cout<<ost_r<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете конкретнее описать свою проблему? У меня ни один компилятор это не стал компилировать. У вас ошибка компиляции? Или неправильно работает? Как именно работает?

Comment: Ошибка тут -  в использовании цикла в принципе...

Comment: @PinkTux как иначе тогда?

Comment: Считайте входящее число как строку, и выводите всё, что после точки. Второй способ: не сравнивать с нулём (потому что ноль почти никогда не получится), а проверять, что полученное значение меньше некоторого небольшого `eps` (по модулю).

Comment: @Zealint ost_r продолжает увеличиваться в цикле, когда следовало бы остановится

Comment: Что вы хотите выводить для 23.00018? Для 23.345678? 18 и 345678? Или 0 и 345?

Comment: @Harry
00018 и 345678

Comment: `unsigned long fractional = (p - floor(p)) * 1000`. Если надо больше 3 знаков - соответственно, `* 10000` для 4, `* 100000` для 5 и т.д. С учётом погрешности в представлении `double`, конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специфика чисел с плавающей точкой в том, что вы никогда не можете почти ничего гарантировать. Например, вы вводите 2.33, но на самом деле будет храниться число наподобие `2.3300000000000000711`, или вместо `2.3456789`
- `2.3456788999999997891`.

Так что вывод будет очень неожиданным для вас.

Поэтому я вижу только такие *реальные* пути...

1. Застолбить количество знаков. Скажем, три после точки. Тогда просто - берете только дробную часть, умножаете на `10^N`, и выводите целую часть.
2. Просто вводите как строку, выводите то, что после точки...
3. Пишете работу с *рациональными* числами вида `p/q` и работаете с ними :)

Comment: По 1-му способу. А если на ввод попадет число с 2-мя знаками после точки

Comment: @topl3niy Третьим будет ноль :)

Comment: но мне он не нужен:с нужна именно дробная часть (1,2 или 3 числа после точки)

Comment: Уж проверить последние ноли на наличие в трехзначном числе проще всего...